# Installing PHP library for Supervisor

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to install [PHP Supervisor](https://github.com/supervisorphp/supervisor) library.

I tried to install the libraries using the following composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "supervisorphp/supervisor": "^3.0",
        "lstrojny/fxmlrpc": "0.10.0",
        "egeloen/http-adapter": "*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle" : "*"
    }
}
```

then running

```
composer update
```

Then, I am trying to run the following [sample program](https://github.com/supervisorphp/supervisor)

```
<?php    
use Supervisor\Supervisor;

use Supervisor\Connector\XmlRpc;
use fXmlRpc\Client;
use fXmlRpc\Transport\HttpAdapterTransport;
use Ivory\HttpAdapter\Guzzle6HttpAdapter;

//Create GuzzleHttp client
$guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['auth' => ['user', '123']]);

// Pass the url and the guzzle client to the XmlRpc Client
$client = new Client(
    'http://127.0.0.1:9001/RPC2',
    new HttpAdapterTransport(new Guzzle6HttpAdapter($guzzleClient))
);

// Pass the client to the connector
// See the full list of connectors bellow
$connector = new XmlRpc($client);

$supervisor = new Supervisor($connector);

// returns Process object
$process = $supervisor->getProcess('test_process');

// returns array of process info
$supervisor->getProcessInfo('test_process');

// same as $supervisor->stopProcess($process);
$supervisor->stopProcess('test_process');

// Don't wait for process start, return immediately
$supervisor->startProcess($process, false);

// returns true if running
// same as $process->checkState(Process::RUNNING);
$process->isRunning();

// returns process name
echo $process;

// returns process information
$process->getPayload();
```

I get the following error

```
Class 'GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request' not found in /test/vendor/egeloen/http-adapter/src/Guzzle6HttpAdapter.php on line 135
```

Comment: Looks like your you need to upgrade Guzzle to V7 or change this to use a V7 version `use Ivory\HttpAdapter\Guzzle6HttpAdapter;`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run the program using the following compose.json file on PHP 5.4.14

```
{
    "require": {
        "supervisorphp/configuration": "^0.2.0",
        "supervisorphp/supervisor": "^3.0",
        "lstrojny/fxmlrpc": "0.10.0",
        "php-http/guzzle5-adapter" : "*",
        "egeloen/http-adapter" : "*"
    }
}
```

Also, following is the program

```
<?php    
use Supervisor\Supervisor;

use Supervisor\Connector\XmlRpc;
use fXmlRpc\Client;
use fXmlRpc\Transport\HttpAdapterTransport;
use Ivory\HttpAdapter\Guzzle5HttpAdapter;

//Create GuzzleHttp client
$guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['auth' => ['user', '123']]);

// Pass the url and the guzzle client to the XmlRpc Client
$client = new Client(
    'http://127.0.0.1:9001/RPC2',
    new HttpAdapterTransport(new Guzzle5HttpAdapter($guzzleClient))
);

// Pass the client to the connector
// See the full list of connectors bellow
$connector = new XmlRpc($client);

$supervisor = new Supervisor($connector);

// returns Process object
$process = $supervisor->getProcess('test_process');

// returns array of process info
$supervisor->getProcessInfo('test_process');

// same as $supervisor->stopProcess($process);
$supervisor->stopProcess('test_process');

// Don't wait for process start, return immediately
$supervisor->startProcess($process, false);

// returns true if running
// same as $process->checkState(Process::RUNNING);
$process->isRunning();

// returns process name
echo $process;

// returns process information
$process->getPayload();
```